# an error when I used ammo.js and physi.js , what should I do for it?

Tags: three.js, physijs, ammo.js

I want to use Physi.js to make a car , but there has some error, I view my demo at Chrome, and I don't know the error is caused by the file named ammo.js or physi.js ,and following are my codes:

```
var phymaterial = Physijs.createMaterial(new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:0xff0000,wireframe:true}),0,1);

//create a wall
var wall1 = new Physijs.BoxMesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,10,2),meshGray);
wall1.position.set(0,5,35);
scene.add(wall1);

var cubegeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(31.6,6,13.6);

//create a cube as car's body

var carPhy = new Physijs.BoxMesh(cubegeo,phymaterial,0);
carPhy.position.set(0,5,0)

car.position.set(0.6,-3,0)
scene.add(carPhy);

//create four wheels use Physijs

var wheelfl = new Physijs.CylinderMesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(4,4,1,30),phymaterial,100);
wheelfl.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
wheelfl.position.set(10,4,-8)
scene.add(wheelfl);
var wheelfr = new Physijs.CylinderMesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(4,4,1,30),phymaterial,100);
wheelfr.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
wheelfr.position.set(10,4,8)
scene.add(wheelfr);
var wheelbl = new Physijs.CylinderMesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(4,4,1,30),phymaterial,100);
wheelbl.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
wheelbl.position.set(-10,4,-8)
scene.add(wheelbl);
var wheelbr = new Physijs.CylinderMesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(4,4,1,30),phymaterial,100);
wheelbr.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
wheelbr.position.set(-10,4,8)
scene.add(wheelbr);

//create constraint with Physijs.DOFConstraint

var fl = new Physijs.DOFConstraint(wheelfl,carPhy,new THREE.Vector3(10,4,-10));
scene.addConstraint(fl);
var fr = new Physijs.DOFConstraint(wheelfr,carPhy,new THREE.Vector3(10,4,10));
scene.addConstraint(fr);
var bl = new Physijs.DOFConstraint(wheelbl,carPhy,new THREE.Vector3(-10,4,-10));
scene.addConstraint(bl);
var br = new Physijs.DOFConstraint(wheelbr,carPhy,new THREE.Vector3(-10,4,10));
scene.addConstraint(br);
```

And the error information like following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _emscripten_bind_btGeneric6DofConstraint_btGeneric6DofConstraint_4 is not defined
    at new btGeneric6DofConstraint (ammo.js:22)
    at Object.public_functions.addConstraint (physijs_worker.js:873)
    at self.onmessage (physijs_worker.js:1412)
```

I wanna know how can I resolve it?